# Client certificate selection

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a https apache server that needs client verification. But when somebody is browsing this site there is need to select proper cert from list of certificates installed in browsers. What can I do to become client cert default to my webpage (so clients do no need to select cert)

Comment: Cross-posted to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554065/client-certificate-selection)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web browser. Some (such as IE, Opera or Chrome) *always* ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think most browsers and servers will allow the server to specify a list of CAs that would be acceptable issues for authenticating to the server.